# Sharing the same state feature in multiple Angular modules [ngrx]

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

Is it possible to manage the same state feature in two or more Angular modules?

What happens if I tried to register the same state feature in two Angular modules? do all the registered reducers get executed, or only one is taken into account?

Context : I need this info because I need to manipulate some state features that are encapsulated inside some node modules (SAP Spartacus modules)

Answer (score 0):

If you register the same reducer with a different feature name, then you will have 3 different state slices reacting to the same actions.
If you register the reducer with the same feature name, then the state context is shared and an action will only trigger the reducer once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 
what if i registered the same feature name with a different reducer in another angular module, which reducer get executed ?

Comment: I think the first one

Comment: How Angular defines which one is first ?

Comment: First come, first served.

Comment: How the order is defined ? like how can i know which one is first ?